# scrollbar appears wrong on ItemsCotrol of a grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, itemscontrol

I have Itemscontrol in the 3rd column of my grid which shows some set of buttons which gets loaded dynamically.
I wanted these contents (i.e. buttons) to occupy maximum width of Grid. and when contents exceeds Grid size, it will show vertical scrollbar.

I applied Scrollbar style to ItemsControl as follows :

```
<Style x:Key="ItemControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                        <Border>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                          CanContentScroll="True"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                          Uid="ScrollViewer_9"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                Uid="ItemsPresenter_5" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have also applied **HorizontalAlignment** and **VerticalAllignMent** as "Stretch" for both ItemsControl as well as its parent i.e. Grid.

**Output view I want is( 3rd column of grid)**
[image]

**Output I am getting is :**
[image]

Scrollbar should appear after size exceeds
How to adjust these contents horizontally to Grid's max width?

Comment: Is it just a case of adding HorizontalAlignment=Stretch to ScrollViewer?

Comment: sorry, I dont get what you are asking. but let me tell you what I want is, these buttons inside ItemsControl are fixed to the single 'line'(as in 2nd Image). I want the contents to occupy whole Column's width and then make it scroll if number of contents exceed column size. Let me put another image which will show after when Scrollbar should come.

Comment: Have added answer with what I mean

Comment: You modified scrollviewer controltemplate to acheive this style?

Comment: I just added `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` to `ScrollViewer`. I haven't touched its template.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just a case of adding **`HorizontalAlignment=Stretch`** to `ScrollViewer`?

ie:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <Border>
                    <ScrollViewer  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                   CanContentScroll="True"
                                   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                   Uid="ScrollViewer_9"
                                   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                         <ItemsPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                         KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                         SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                         Uid="ItemsPresenter_5" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Tried this also, but still getting output same as 'output I am getting' image. but while doing this I came across putting items in wrappanel. I increased size of wrap panel to 2times width of my button template. now I get what I expected but without using scrollBar. if I use scrollbar then it again gives previous wrong output